# Changing the global scope variable inside of a function with click handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm building a turn based game with javascript and jquery and I'm currently struggling with limiting player movement. 
So this is what I have:

```
let playerOneMoves = 0;
let playerTwoMoves = 0;

function movePlayerOne(){
    $(tile).click(function(){
        playerOneMoves += 1;
        if(playerOneMoves < 4){
            $(".active").append(playerOne);
        }else if(playerOneMoves == 4){
            alert("No more moves, players two turn!");            
            playerTwoMoves = 0;
            movePlayerTwo();

        }
    })
}
function movePlayerTwo(){
    $(tile).click(function(){
        playerTwoMoves += 1;
        if(playerTwoMoves < 4){
            $(".active").append(playerTwo);
        }else if(playerTwoMoves == 4){
            playerOneMoves = 0;
            alert("No more moves, players one turn!")
            movePlayerOne();

        }   
    })
}
```

So as player 2 finishes his move, and the next function (moveplayerone) is loaded, I only have 1 move with player 1. After a few more clicks, it starts appending both players to the same field.
So my question is, why can't I reset the value of "let playerOneMoves = 0;" inside of a function? 
If you want to see the code more in-depth, you can check it on CodePen: 
https://codepen.io/ronydkid/pen/oyqxJY

Btw, I've checked all the other similar questions but they weren't helpful.

Comment: Try using var instead of let? Also your codepen link doesn't work :/

Comment: your codepen link gives `404`?

Comment: I've tried using var but it doesn't change anything. Sorry about codepen link, updated it, it works now :)

Comment: @Scath What purpose would there be in intentionally downgrading to `var`? Isn't `let`, with it's lack of hoisting and block scope, always more intuitive and less bug-prone?

Comment: You're assigning click handlers multiple times to the same element and eventually what happens is that you click on an element and several handles handle the event, incrementing the values and redoing them to zero.

Comment: basically every time you call your function, you're assigning another click handler

Comment: are you trying to trigger it ? by doing `$(tile).click(movePlayerOne);` where `movePlayerOne` also includes a `click` binding ?

Comment: So how can I reduce player moves on every click without the click handler?
Sorry, bit new to jquery and js

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That's just a mistake in codepen, in original code function is called on body load

Comment: umm.. until you can reproduce it with the actual set of code, that you have it is confusing to suggest anything

Comment: What's the game's objective and basic rules. Sometimes knowing that helps us to recognize what could be a waste of time

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Sorry, but the codepen doesn't give me an option to put a body tag. I've updated the codepen to load a function i js file :)

Comment: @zer00ne The game objecetive is to have 2 players that each have 3 moves per turn. If they get close to each other, a fight between them needs to start, there should be random weapon spawns on the map, but a bunch of that stuff is not in the code yet since I'm struggling with player movement right now. For now, the objective is to limit the player movement to 3 tiles per turn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we're going to semantically read your functions from top to bottom

## movePlayerOne

1. Assign a click handler

## movePlayerTwo

1. Assign a click handler

That doesn't seem like the intended functionality you're after! I'm guessing what you wanted was that on click, you need to check your moves, and then assign which player is the active player. This should be handled with a single click handler that has knowledge of which player's turn it is. To achieve this lets go ahead and make a DIFFERENT click handler called `movePlayer` and a new global called `currentPlayer`

```
let currentPlayer = playerOne;
let playerOneMoves = 0;
let playerTwoMoves = 0;
let active = $(".active"); // we don't want to crawl DOM every time unless needed,
// so unless you're destroying the ".active" DOM object every time, you should be fine here

function movePlayer(){
  let currentMoves = currentPlayer == playerOne
    ? ++playerOneMoves
    : ++playerTwoMoves;
  if ( currentMoves < 4 ){
    active.append(currentPlayer);
  } else { // basically if we get here we've reached 4 moves
    if (currentPlayer == playerOne) {
      currentPlayer = playerTwo;
      playerOneMoves = 0;
      alert("No more moves, players two's turn!");
    } else {
      currentPlayer = playerOne;
      playerTwoMoves = 0;
      alert("No more moves, players one turn!");
    }
  }
}

$(tile).click(movePlayer)
```

Now whenever you click on a tile only one function gets run, and this function handles moves for BOTH players and it doesn't register more click handlers

---

Some of the shortcuts used:

## [Ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
if (condition) {
  console.log('true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```

can be rewritten with a ternary as

```
console.log( condition ? 'true' : 'false' )
```

## Increment

```
var i = 0;
console.log(i++) // 0
console.log(i) // 1
console.log(++i) // 2
console.log(i) // 2
```

---

## Notes on other changes you can make

If you don't need the extra references to individual player moves variables, take a look at @geekley 's answer below. It's a little smaller and features hoisting of non evaluated variables, short circuiting the function in a conditional, and less variables.

Comment: That saved me a lot of time now! I'm super grateful! Thaaank you very much, very appreciated!

Comment: glad to help. Click handlers can be a little confusing

Comment: Indeed, thought I have to add a click handler for every action that needs to run some function

Comment: @RonyDKid The question title and some content feels little confusing now for people who reach here looking for something else related to the global scope. The problem is how to update the question so that people find it now when looking for the problem you faced, which was registering multiple click handlers

Comment: How do you suggest I rename it?

Comment: probably changing the end of it to 'with click handlers' instead of 'inside of a function'

Comment: Did it. Thanks again. Just one more question, since I'm triyng to also understand the code and not just copy paste it, could you elaborate on what are the question marks used for before incrementation? Bassicly if you could explain what this does, i'd be endlessly grateful: 
? ++playerOneMoves
    : ++playerTwoMoves

Comment: sure. It's called a ternary expression. It's like an inline if else. `true ? 'yes' : 'no` or `false` ? 'no' : 'yes'` should be simple enough examples to copy and paste. More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thank you! Again, endlessly grateful mate!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you mean?

```
let playerMoves = 0;
let currentPlayer = 1;

$(tile).click(movePlayer);
function movePlayer() {
    playerMoves += 1;
    if (playerMoves < 4) {
        $(".active").append(currentPlayer == 1 ? playerOne : playerTwo);
        return;
    }
    // if (playerMoves >= 4) {
        if (currentPlayer == 1) {
            alert("No more moves, player two's turn!");
            currentPlayer = 2;
        } else { // currentPlayer == 2
            alert("No more moves, player one's turn!");
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
        playerMoves = 0;
    // }
}
```

Comment: I thought about condensing too but I ran into the connundrum of 'what if he references those variables elsewhere...'

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to respond and find an answer! I'll try it out too since I'm curious if ti works :D

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much assumed that both players are "symmetrical", like, they work the same way, just each on their own turn. But it could not have been the case.

Comment: It does due to hoisting. @geekley does however condense some of the some condensing of variables and short circuiting in their fix though

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the let... the problem is your code structure:

```
let playerMoves = 0;
let player = 1;
$(tile).click(function() {
    if (playerMoves < 4) {
        $(".active").append(player == 1 ? playerOne : playerTwo);
        playerMoves += 1;
    }
    if (playerMoves == 4) {
        playerMoves = 0;
        player == 1 ? player = 2 : player = 1;
        alert("No more moves, " + player + "'s turn!");    
    }
});
```